# How do I copy text from my PC to my phone?

Tags: sync, cloud, copy-paste

I am looking for a way to copy text from my home computer to my phone, sort of a shared clipboard. Right now I go to the [zxing QR code generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) and paste the code, take a picture of the screen with the phone, and set the barcode scanner to copy text to the clipboard. It seems like there should be a simpler way. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install the **[WiFi Keyboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-keyboard/com.volosyukivan)** app from Android Market. A good app, supports both USB and WiFi input. You need to follow information carefully, to get work around.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The WIFI Keyboard works great. I'm more and more amazed of what's possible with our little devices  :)

Comment: Great! Now I'm not scared of those password fields anymore!

Comment: Some more information would be useful, to make it a complete.

Comment: The app is longer on Google Play :(

Answer (score 15):

[Chrome-to-Phone](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-chrome-to-phone/com.google.android.apps.chrometophone)

Comment: Looks interesting, but I like that WiFi Keyboard does not require any software on the PC, just a wifi connection.

Comment: chrome to phone doesn't require any software too, and it's simpler in its use than WiFi keyboard, you just highlight the text you want to copy then click on the icon besides the address bar in your chrome browser

Comment: Sadly, it says "This item is not available on your carrier" :(

Comment: That app is longer on Google Play :(

Answer (score 10):

Google <del>Docs</del>Drive allows collaborative editing between [phone app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs) and webapp. Updates typically propogate from one to the other within a few seconds, and just appear in the document on the updated device, with markup to show that it came from someone else.

I use it for brainstorming sessions with my colleagues on the go, I like it better than SMS/Email because it's easier to see what they're talking about (their text appears in the pertinent part of the document)

Comment: As of now the new "Docs" native android Apps is awesome: it shows you live the text being taped on your PC!!! Thanks for sharing this trics!

Answer (score 8):

Try [ClipSync](http://bdwm.be/cs)

It's an app I have written that will update the clipboard on your PC once it has detected a change in the android clipboard over WiFi. (And vice versa.)

So you can do:

- ctr+c (win) -> long press - paste (android).
- long press - copy (android) -> ctrl+v (win).

Answer (score 5):

**[QRCopy](http://qrcopy.net)** is a free app that lets you share your clipboard between your PC and nearly any other device.  It uses qr codes to transfer information, so it works on any device that has a QR code reader.  The Windows version includes a fast QR code reader that works using your webcam, and it has a mobile app that runs on most other devices.  Once you have some text in your clipboard you just press windows-v and it pops up in an onscreen qr code ready for you to scan using your mobile.  To send text back to your pc you use it's qr code generator on your mobile to copy your text to a qr code, then on your pc you just press windows-c and it will fire up your webcam and use it to read the qr code on your mobile device.  It only takes a second or two, and it works in any program.

http://www.qrcopy.net

[Disclaimer: I am a friend of the guy who created QRCopy.]

Comment: Perfectly valid answer IMO. Worked great for me. There's a bug (or a feature?) however. I wan't able to type my text into the text box on the page, just the URL bar.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Pushbullet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pushbullet.android) app (also requires the [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pushbullet/chlffgpmiacpedhhbkiomidkjlcfhogd?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) for windows). It's includes universal copy and paste (currently only supported on Android and Windows).

> To enable the feature, you'll have to go to the advanced settings on
>   each device you want to sync. Once you turn it on, copying text on one
>   device will automatically send it to the clipboard of all the others.
>   The developers state they're working on adding iOS and OS X support,
>   but for now it works pretty well between Android and Windows devices.

Comment: How, specifically, does this solve the OP's problem?

Comment: PushBullet has a shared clipboard between Android devices and your PC when Pushbullet is installed in chrome and on the android devices.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). It has a clipboard feature and works over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Works like a charm. Allows sending files, URLs, and app APK's as well. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Clipboard doesn't work on newer phones.

Answer (score 4):

Use [UniClip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piyushagade.uniclip). It has a desktop client, with global keyboard shortcuts to copy, paste text to/from your other devices.

**To copy text from PC to Android,**

1. Copy a text in your PC, then hit CTRL + Shift + C.
2. Your mobile will be notify you about the incoming clip, you might have to shake your mobile few times (this can be changed in preferences) to copy the
   clip to your mobile's clipboard.

**To copy text from Android to PC**:

1. Copy some text on your mobile device.
2. You will be notified of an incoming clip on your PC, press Ctrl + Shift + V to put the  clip on your PC's clipboard. And then paste it like usual on any
   application.

Download the desktop client from: [piyushagade.xyz/uniclip](http://piyushagade.xyz/uniclip)

**Features:**

1. Users can decide if/which their devices should update their clipboards. So, if you want only only one of your device to update their clipboards, then you can achieve this by shaking only that particular device.
2. The applications are very light on resources.
3. Android application maintains session's clipboard history.

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the app

Answer (score 3):

I use a standard text file synchronized through Dropbox. Works in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Thats is easy! Have whatsapp running on your PC. And paste/write text on to your account and access it on phone immediately!! enjoy the super fast sync. 
and the other way around to get it on PC.

No extra apps, whatsapp is always on the most easily accessible part on your phone anyways! 
and you always have a history. Who else messages yourself on whatsapp? :)

Answer (score 3):

[clipbrd](http://www.clipbrd.com/) is a chrome extension and android app works great across multiple pcs, macs, and android phones

Answer (score 2):

I wrote bash script that will do that (for linux). It will require internet too. All you need to do is

1. create a launcher for the script and put it on the panel.
2. Highlight the text you want to transfer and click on the launcher.
3. A barcode will appear on the screen and you can scan that.

[Link to script](http://balkierode.blogspot.com/2011/04/quick-script-to-copy-text-to-android.html)

Answer (score 2):

I use Evernote to sync text between PC and phone.

Answer (score 2):

I use [AutoRemote](https://joaoapps.com/autoremote/) and Tasker to copy text, as well as files. It does have a steep learning curve to use it, but it is an extremely powerful tool to transfer data, and there are many tutorials online to help.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Alt-C](https://altcopy.net/) app. It has 2 parts a small desktop application that runs in the system tray and an Android app. Basically, you copy any text with the keyboard shortcut alt-c and then you can long click and paste it on your phone and vice-versa for a phone to PC copy paste. The advantage this app has over ClipSync and Clipbrd(Both apps I've used before), is that Clipsync only works if both your device are on the same wifi network and Clipbrd requires you to keep Chrome browser running, which eats up resources. Also unlike other apps that only allow copying and pasting a single item, Alt-C keeps a list of up to 50 items synced across your devices.Personally, I feel the ideal solution would be a clipboard manager app like Ditto or 1Clipboard with cross-platform cloud synced shared clipboard.

Comment: So how does Alt-C work since you said clip synch needs devices to be in same network?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat they pass the data through their cloud servers.

Comment: +1 but then its also a disadvantage if you're not exclusively connected to an internet connection. I prefer local connection however, but this is still worth a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I use airdroid.
But a very simple & handy solution should be with default APP.
gmail is installed in everyone's mobile -android/iOS (I think)

- goto gmail in browser
- type anything in new message
- close it. this saves it in draft.
- Open gmail APP in mobile.
- Goto draft. You will find your message (text) over there.

Answer (score 0):

I have skype on my pc and phone. if i like a url i can paste it into there and send it to any address then it pops up on my phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [My-Clipboard.com](https://my-clipboard.com), paste from phone (browser/app), then open in browser on PC and click copy :)

Answer (score 0):

Many good solutions in this thread, my suggestion is Snapcopy (http://snapcopyapp.com/) that i've used for some time now and does exactly what OP needed. Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide steps to use this for the objective?

Comment: Sure: 1. Install the app 2. Install the chrome extension 3. Copy, paste

Answer (score 0):

You can use my app, Reader’S Checkpoints (RSC) which supports this functionality. The app can be downloaded free from Google Playstore, [here is the link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.navneet.readercheckpoint). With this app installed on your android phone, all you have to do is, head over to the website http://rscweb.in/ on the computer from which you need to transfer the text and click “send text to phone”. On the field that you see just type in/paste the text which you need to send to your android phone. Now click “Generate QR”, a new QR code will be generated. Now just open the Reader’S Checkpoints (RSC) app and scan the QR from your computer to receive the text instantly on your app.

Further details regarding the app can be [found here](https://www.freshbytelabs.com/2020/02/easily-share-text-from-your-android.html)

The app also offers a ton of other features like sharing text from android device to computer, adding a note and sharing it using a unique url, share text from any app on your phone to pc without even opening the Reader’S Checkpoints (RSC) etc.

Answer (score 0):

try https://etell.me no registration needed. Simply create a customised tag e.g https://etell.me/my-temp-text and you can update text there e.g on your phone; then visit the same URL on your laptop. It’s based on Google Firestore so the data are synced between devices on the fly.