# Sending text from Android to PC

Tags: wi-fi

I'm looking for the inverse of [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/is-there-an-application-to-copy-text-from-my-pc-to-my-phone/).
I want to quickly transfer a piece of text from android to my computer. One way to do is chat with myself using gtalk or fb. But I'm looking for some better way preferably without using Internet and using wifi only. It would be nice if I have a "People nearby app" that can talk with empathy client.

Comment: "Without using Internet and using wifi" doesn't make sense to me.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Matthew I think he means over wifi (or bluetooth?) only

Comment: Yes, by means of wifi or bluetooth only.

Comment: @Matthew Read: Strange as it may seem in this age of "cloud", it is quite possible to have a local IP network without any Internet access. For example, if your ISP has a service outage, this is unlikely to affect communication between devices on your home (internal) network - e.g. your media center, the gaming console, the desktop computer and the droid will still "see" each other. (See my answer for an example of a LAN app)

Comment: @Piskvor Yeah, I know. I was hoping for clarification on the situation, since he doesn't specify he wants it only to work when the devices are on the same network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an app called *Remote Web Desktop* by SmartDog Studio. It enables access to your phone through your desktop's browser, over the local network (i.e. no connection to the Internet is necessary (I use it with both phone and desktop on the same WiFi AP); phone acts as HTTP(S) server on non-standard port (configurable)).

The simplest method is "shared clipboard": select the text on your phone, copy to clipboard, and it's immediately accessible from the desktop computer.

The app has a [free (ad-supported)](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.xdevelop.rm) and [paid (~$4 USD)](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.xdevelop.rmp) version; the free version allows connection over HTTP, paid also offers HTTPS.

---

Full disclosure: I'm a (happy) user of this app, no other connection.

Answer (score 0):

[Catch](http://www.appbrain.com/app/catch-notes/com.threebanana.notes) synchronizes notes from various sources (PC or phone) automatically.  Unfortunately it requires an internet connection, but that can be via wifi and not the phone's data plan.  So, while not ideal, I think it's better than sending yourself FB chat messages.

Answer (score -1):

If your PC and phone both support blue tooth you should be able to tether the two together.
Alternatively you should be able to use a USB chord to attach your phone as a USB device and drag and drop from your phone's data to your PC; I can do this with my HTC EVO 4G.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Bluetooth tethering in and of itself doesn't provide a way to quickly transfer text, and creating text files and moving them via USB seems like a really clunky method.

Comment: I agree with Maththew...

Comment: Yes, I don't want to transfer text files. I just want to transfer clipboard contents - a phone number or sms or bookmark or a memo etc.,

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.watchbird.scaan

This works perfectly fine for sharing text or link between your android and computer browser.

More info at http://www.scaan.in/

Note: I am the developer of this app. It is new to Play Store, but you can trust that this app is a final product, that has undergone thorough testing

Comment: Note that our policy on promotion requires disclosure in every single post where affiliated product is mentioned. Furthermore, don't just mention the links. Explain how to use the app to achieve the objective in question.