# How to share clipboard between Android devices, preferably without need for internet connection

Tags: sync, copy-paste

Is there a way to share the contents of the clipboard between Android device similar to how it is done with Windows?

Basically I am looking for a similar method as asked here: [How do I copy text from my PC to my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3537/209414), but I want to to this with my smartphone (running Android 7.0) and tablet (running Android 4.3).

From the post above (and many others already posted on Android Stackexchange) there are many tools to do that with Android/Windows devices and I use [Clipsync](https://clipsync.bdwm.be/) for that, nevertheless I was unsuccessful when I tried to setup with Android/Android devices.

**Things I have tried**

- I recently tried to do that with [Join](https://joaoapps.com/join/) but its is not working and I can't login to access the features (also it needs internet).
- Also I tried to use [Roamit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghiasi.roamitapp&hl=en) which looking promising but it is not supportes on Android 4.3 devices.
- I tried to setup Autoremote with Tasker as described [here](https://www.pocketables.com/2013/06/use-autoremote-and-tasker-to-copy-text-to-your-device-from-other-devices.html) but I am stuck in setting up the task.
- I was hoping to also use to QR code method but couldn't find a working one

I am looking for a method that uses **bluetooth/local access** to share clipboard contents **between android devices**with no creation of additional files such as `.html` files.

Comment: I recommend Clipboard Actions & Manager also on Izzy's list. It can transfer the content of the clipboard via Bluetooth and more. A html file will be transferred between the devices with the clipboard content.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thanks but I was hoping for an option which doesn't create additional files like .html, something more like clipsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Izzy's trove of curated apps
[Paste Easy](https://pasteasy.en.aptoide.com/?store_name=apps&app_id=10173077) (that can be downloaded from Aptoide) was suggested. Reason being that this app caters to early versions of KitKat which is OP's requirement. I didn't try the app but OP has confirmed that it meets the bill.

For alternatives, see [Multi Device Clipboard](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard) 
on Izzy's list.